# How to implement in-memory queue in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, queue

I know it's bad practice, but I would like to implement in-memory queue (of integers) in MySQL.
The queue will be up to 5000 elements long at most.

The queue will be pushed and popped in parallel by 1000 processes at the same time.

I don't want to use tables. I would like to implement the queue using stored procedures / functions

Anyone can suggest a solution / references / ideas for the task above?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered the [`MEMORY` storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)?

Comment: "in-memory" doesn't really make sense in this context, for such a relatively small amount of data everything will be buffered in RAM anyway ...

Comment: I don't want to use tables. I would like to implement the queue using stored procedures / functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two interesting articles about this issue:

http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2012/03/15/job-queue-in-mysql.html

https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you/